# Android custom listview row wont let me add

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview which is working fine just using simple_list_view1. But now I need to add an icon to the left. So i've created a iconrow.xml in res/layout/. When I try and set that as the layout it errors and wont let me use `android.R.layout.iconrow,`. Clearly i'm doing something wrong here! It's an array being built up that will populate the data.

My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My code is:

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SQLStatement, null);
    if(c.getCount() != 0) {

```
Log.e("LocationListView", "Found Items");   

c.moveToFirst();
```

ArrayList mItemName = new ArrayList();
  final ArrayList mItemID = new ArrayList();

```
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
     mItemName.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name")));
     mItemID.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ColType)));
     c.moveToNext();
}
rowCount = mItemName.size();

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLocation);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.iconrow, android.R.id.text1, mItemName);

int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; 
listView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
listView.setDividerHeight(1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

listView.setClickable(true);
```

The error is on the android.R.layout.iconrow

Any help will be appreciated.

Tom

EDIT: Here is my code now - The errors on  tv.setText(mItemName.get(arg0).toString());

```
     c.moveToFirst();


      final ArrayList<String> mItemID = new ArrayList<String>();

        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
             mItemName.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name")));
             mItemID.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ColType)));
             c.moveToNext();
        }
        rowCount = mItemName.size();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLocation);

//        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//                R.layout.iconrow, R.id.text, mItemName);
        tv.setText(mItemName.get(arg0).toString()); 

        int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; 
        listView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
        listView.setDividerHeight(1);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());

        listView.setClickable(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String StationObjectID = mItemID.get(position);

            Intent SwapPage = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), LocationListView.class);
            SwapPage.putExtra("ID", StationObjectID);
            SwapPage.putExtra("Type", Type);

            startActivityForResult(SwapPage, 0);

          }
        });

        } else {

            Log.e("LocationListView", "Not Found Items");   
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "No data returned";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();       

        }

        db.close();

    }

        public void goBack(View view) {

            if(Global.returnPage.equals("MainPage")) {  

            Intent addItem = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainPage.class);
            startActivityForResult(addItem, 0);

            } else {
                Intent addItem = new Intent(view.getContext(), LocationListView.class);
                addItem.putExtra("Type", Global.stepListType);
                Log.e("PushThrough", Global.stepListType);
                addItem.putExtra("ID", Global.stepListID);
                Log.e("PushThrough", Global.stepListID);
                startActivityForResult(addItem, 0);
            }
        }


        public void addItem(View view){
            Intent addItem = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddItem.class);
            addItem.putExtra("Count", rowCount);

            if(Adding.equals("Building")){

                addItem.putExtra("Type", "0");

            } else if(Adding.equals("Room")){

                addItem.putExtra("Type", "1001");
                addItem.putExtra("PrevID", dataID);

            } else if (Adding.equals("Area")){

                addItem.putExtra("Type", "532");
                addItem.putExtra("PrevID", dataID);
            }

                startActivityForResult(addItem, 0);
        }

        public void onResume()
        {
            super.onResume();

           Log.e("Tom", "resumed");
        }


        class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mItemName.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inf=getLayoutInflater();
            View v=inf.inflate(R.layout.iconrow, arg2,true);

            ImageView iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);

            return v;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i think you need to inflate using just R.layout.iconrow

Comment: simply replace android.R.layout.iconrow with R.layout.iconrow. You dont want to access the androids layout, do you? Did you implement an custom adapter?

Comment: or if u need to have somemore info check http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/custom-list-view.html or http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom Adapter as

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mItemName.size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inf=getLayoutInflater();
        View v=inf.inflate(R.layout.iconrow, arg2,true);

        ImageView iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);

        return v;
    }

}
```

and then set this to your list as

```
listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to do this but I'm getting errors mItemName.size isn't declared and LayoutInflater inf=getLayoutInflater(); The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type CustomRow

Comment: mItemName is your ArrayList, so declare it globaly in your class not in any method........ and what is CustomRow??? And one more thing also..... make CustomAdapter class a inner class in your main class

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I set the items from the arrays to the listview now?

Comment: tv.setText(mitemName.get(arg0).toString()); .........and please accept Answer if it works

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. Really appreciate it. I've updated my code below in my question as i'm clearly doing something wrong and can't work it out

Comment: tv cannot be resolved - arg0 cannot be resolved to a variable. I don't get how my cursor is being set to the table now too

Comment: ok........ you have to write tv.setText(mitemName.getText().toString()) in your getView() method of CustomAdapter class..........

Comment: I get that, i've done that now. But it's erroring still - 10-10 14:31:20.200: E/AndroidRuntime(13975): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
10-10 14:31:20.200: E/AndroidRuntime(13975):  at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:471)
I don't see what sets up the data to be transfered to the view?

Comment: oh sorry i have made 1 mistake while inflating view........So just replace true with false in getView() method..... View v=inf.inflate(R.layout.iconrow, arg2,false);

Comment: Oh Thanks. So will the image be arg2 or arg1? I'm trying to see how to set my image from the database array

Comment: The int variable arg0 tells us the index or position of item in the list.......so you have to use arg0 only.

Comment: Ah! All makes sense now! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation is as follows:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Applications>{
    private MainActivity context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private int textresourceId;
   ArrayList<Applications> objects=null;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(MainActivity context, int resource,ArrayList<Applications> objects) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
        Log.d("CustomArrayAdapter","Was here!!");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return objects.size();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inf=getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView=inf.inflate(R.layout.iconrow, arg2,true);

        ImageView iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```